# What's the difference between using "<>"&"" vs. "<>" in Google Sheets formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

For Google Sheets, I've seen people use both `=COUNTIF(range,"<>"&"")` as well as `=COUNTIF(range,"<>")` to count the number of non-empty cells in a range.

Is there any difference, benefit, or concern, using one approach over the other?

Comment: please [edit] your question and provide a clear example of the formula you are using.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

No difference. **`&""`** is redundant.

#### A.  They are equivalent

The formulas **`="<>"&""`** and **`="<>"`** both return **`<>`**.

This is necessarily so because any text string, whether **`"<>"`** or **`"webAppsRocks"`**, is equivalent to the result of joining nothing else to it.

#### B.  The reason to use `"<>"&""` instead of `"<>"`

1. I don't know a good reason to include **`&""`** in any of the following:

   ```
   =COUNTIF(range,"<>&"") 
   =COUNTIF(range,"<>&""&"")
   =COUNTIF(range,"<>"&""&""&""&""&""&""&""&""&""&"")
   ```
2. Including **`""`** may reflect a lack of experience on the part of users possibly combined with a spillover effect from Microsoft Excel. Even though **`&""`** is redundant in Excel as well, users habitually include empty strings **`""`** in formulas to avoid returning zero values. For example:

   ```
   # Excel Formula Examples
    
   =IF(TRUE,)      =IF(TRUE,"",)
   =0              =[ empty_string ]
    

   =IFERROR(1/0,)  =IFERROR(1/0,"")
   =0              =[ empty_string ]
   ```

#### C.  Why use COUNTIF?

If your goal is to count the number of values in a range or array, COUNTA is designed specifically to do that.

```
=COUNTA(range)   vs.  =COUNTIF(range,"<>")
```